# C# Inherited Indexer: Another Way

Tags: c#, inheritance, indexer

I have an abstract parent class that encapsulates access to an array of MyObjects:

```
public abstract class MyObjectIterator
{
    public MyObjectIterator(MyObject[] MyObjects) { //constructor }

    public Vector2 [] Coords { //A Get Function }

    public Model[] Params { //A Get Function }

    //THIS ISN'T SAFE! CAN STILL CHANGE MEMBERS OF THE SET
    public MyObject[] MyObjects{ get; protected set; }
}
```

A child class of this already implements a single index indexer for another purpose, so I cannot use it to return a MyObject.
However, as it is unsafe/bad practise to return the array, as this means the elements within can be modified, I am looking for a way that I can provide a tidy interface to accessing a single element, e.g.

```
MyObject = Child.MyObjects[i];
```

but without providing `set` access to any element of MyObjects.

A related question I have is: If I have an indexer on a parent class, can this be used when you have an object of a child class?

**Edit:**
I have decided to go with the method
`public MyObject MyObject(int index) { return MyObjects[index]; }`
As it most accomplishes what I was wanting.

Comment: Note that even if the collection is readonly, the `MyObject`s returned can still be edited.  If this is a problem, you might want to do something to only expose clones of the objects, or change `MyObject` from a `class` to a `struct`.

Comment: IMO it'd be better to go with an indexer instead of a method, if you decide to go that route.  It's functionally very similar, but allows for more straightforward declaration and getting.  You also might want to implement `IEnumerable<MyObject>` to allow iterating that way.  Since `IEnumerable` only specifies read access, you wouldn't have to expose any set capability.

Comment: @TimS, I wanted to use an indexer, but because the child classes implement indexers with the same arguments, the parents one is not immediately accessible. Hence the question (The child classes have different return types; if C# could overload based on return type, that would be wonderful...)

Comment: Technically, the .NET framework allows overloading based on return types; however, C# doesn't. If you really want to go and write MSIL, you can get the features you want. Otherwise, your approach or the ReadOnly route (or anything except an indexer with the same arguments) would have to be used.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) class that may accomplish what you are looking for. This acts as a wrapper around the array. Use something like `ReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> Data { get { return array.AsReadOnly(); } }` Mutating the underlying array will affect the ReadOnlyCollection. The collection itself is relatively lightweight, so you could create a new one each time the property is accessed or use caching if the property is accessed frequently (either at call site or within the class itself).

As for your second question, the answer is yes. [Indexers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) are rather like properties. If a property could be inherited (or required, such as due to an interface) an indexer would be as well.

Comment: And to clarify, if the child class implements its own indexer, then the parent one will not be available without casting to a parent?

Comment: Yes; the child implementation would hide the parent's. But if you were using polymorphism, Parent[i] would use the parent's implementation rather than executing the code for Child[i] (if the indexer was hidden instead of overridden [the parent one would have to be virtual]).